# How to get real mac address of VM run on Windows

Tags: wireless-networking, virtual-machine

I can't get virtual box's mac address it run on Windows computer. I find virtual box's mac address is same with windows computer mac address. my windows computer is wifi connection with router.

but I cant get real virtual box's mac address if it run on Ubuntu os, and Ubuntu is cable connection with router.

Who can tell some cause? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In this case OS isn't actually important – the main difference is Wi-Fi versus wired Ethernet.

Since Wi-Fi is wireless, it needs to have more MAC addresses in its header – in addition to the regular Ethernet source/destination MACs, all Wi-Fi frames also need to know the radio sender/receiver (station & AP) MACs, to make sure only the correct device will receive it.

The problem, however, is that regular Wi-Fi clients can only put *one* "sender" field there – it's always assumed that the original sender's MAC will be exactly the same. Likewise, when the AP sends packets, it only puts one "recipient" MAC; it also assumes the receiving station is also the final recipient.

In other words, **a single Wi-Fi connection cannot use different MAC addresses at the same time** (changing the MAC would require a disconnect). So VirtualBox must use ARP-NAT to pretend that it's still the same OS sending the packets.

(There are special Wi-Fi connection modes such as "WDS-Bridge" which allow MAC address spoofing, but they must be supported by both sides – many cheap APs don't include that option, and only Linux supports it on the client side.)